SQL: find specific text between two key words inside sql code
I have a question.
I work with Teradata. I have a syntax in where condition of the filling select that should look up key words "partition by" inside code that is used between select and from clausules, but it returns bad findings because it looks up for "partition by" between the first select and the last from. So it doesn't take into account situation where we have union or nested select in the script.
The check verifies that the object in the begin script section does not contain the keywords "PARTITION BY" (only allowed in the qualify clause at the end of the statement). This is due to the performance complexity of using analysis functions under the reporting tool.
eg. Union:
not finding

finding

First of all, do you have any idea how to modify the syntax so that it looks up for a "partition by" between the first select and the immediately following from in the script?
I tried syntax Table_Begin_Script like '%select%partition by%from%' but it´s not work properly. I only try to find codes in Table_Begin_Script attribute that have "partition by" directly between select and from.
INPUT DATASET




Table_Begin_Script
AQ_Rule_Id
Platform_Alias_1
Database_Name_1
Schema_Name_1
Object_Name_1
Element_Name_1
Platform_Alias_2
Database_Name_2
Schema_Name_2
Object_Name_2
Element_Name_2
Object_Type
AQ_Rule_Type
Finding_Value_1
Finding_Value_2
Finding_Desc
Audit_User
Audit_Process
Audit_TS




replace view %TABLE% as select  cpl1.Product_LOFEX_Id as Product_LOFEX_Id,  coalesce (cpl1.Product_LOFEX_Name, 'Nezname jmeno produktu') as Product_LOFEX_Name,  coalesce (cpl1.Product_LOFEX_Name_En, 'Unknown Product Name') as Product_LOFEX_Name_EN,  cpl1.Product_LOFEX_Type as Product_LOFEX_Type,  cpt1.Product_LOFEX_Type_Name as Product_LOFEX_Type_Name,  cpt1.Product_LOFEX_Type_Name_En as Product_LOFEX_Type_Name_EN from m_lofex.HC_Product_LOFEX cpl1  join m_lofex.C_Product_LOFEX_Type cpt1 on cpl1.Product_LOFEX_Type = cpt1.Product_LOFEX_Type qualify max(End_Date) over(partition by Product_LOFEX_Id)= End_Date  union select  99 as Product_LOFEX_Id,  'Neznamy produkt' as Product_LOFEX_Name,  'Unknown product' as Product_LOFEX_Name_EN,  plt1.Product_LOFEX_Type as Product_LOFEX_Type,  plt1.Product_LOFEX_Type_Name as Product_LOFEX_Type_Name,  plt1.Product_LOFEX_Type_Name_En as Product_LOFEX_Type_Name_EN from m_lofex.C_Product_LOFEX_Type plt1 where plt1.Product_LOFEX_Type = 'X' ;  comment on view %TABLE% is '%TLABL%';
62
PDM

M_LOFEX
VP_C_Product_LOFEX






Object
PDM_F4
Begin script does not contain key words "PARTITION BY" under reporting views

NULL


12.04.2024 08:23:16+02:00


replace view %TABLE% as select  sub5.Date_Valid,  sub5.Source_Entity_Code,  sub5.Entity_Code_7,  sub5.Entity_Code_7

'_'

sub5.Source_Entity_Code as Source_Entity_Id,  sub5.Source_Entity_Code

'1ORG00000' as Org_Unit_Id,  sub5.Global_Reporting_Flag,  sub5.Basel_Party_Group,  sub5.Coll_Instrument_Id,  dc1.Last_Valuation_RiDM_Amt_LC,  dc1.Last_Valuation_RiDM_Amt_EUR,  dc1.Collateral_Nature_Code,  vccn1.Collateral_Nature_Desc,  vccn1.Collateral_Nature_Desc_EN,  dc1.Guarantee_Status,  dc1.Collateral_Scope,  dc1.Covered_Amt_Type,  dc1.Surety_Type,  dc1.Collateral_Sharing_Type,  dc1.STD_Eligibility_Flag,  dc1.Local_Eligibility_Flag,  dc1.Orig_Appraisal_Amt_LC,  dc1.Orig_Appraisal_Amt_EUR,  dc1.Last_Appraisal_Amt_LC,  dc1.Last_Appraisal_Amt_EUR,  dc1.Allocated_Collateral_Amt_LC,  dc1.Allocated_Collateral_Amt_EUR,  dc1.SG_Collateral_Family,  vcsc1.SG_Collateral_Family_Desc,  vcsc1.SG_Collateral_Family_Desc_EN,  dc1.SG_Collateral_Nature,  vcsc2.SG_Collateral_Nature_Desc,  vcsc2.SG_Collateral_Nature_Desc_EN,  dc1.Last_Appraisal_Date,  dc1.Effective_Date,  dc1.Expiration_Date,  dc1.Guarantee_Collateral_Rank,  dc1.Last_Actualization_Date,  sub5.Agreement_Count,  sub5.Global_Exposure_Amt_LC,  sub5.Global_Exposure_Amt_EUR,  dcg1.Guarantor_Count,  sub5.Guarantee_Client_Count from   (   select    sub4.Date_Valid,    sub4.Source_Entity_Code,    sub4.Entity_Code_7,    sub4.Coll_Instrument_Id,    coalesce(count(sub4.Agreement_Id), 0) as Agreement_Count,    sum(sub4.Global_Exposure_Amt_LC) as Global_Exposure_Amt_LC,    sum(sub4.Global_Exposure_Amt_EUR) as Global_Exposure_Amt_EUR,    sub4.Global_Reporting_Flag,    max(sub4.Party_Id_Rank) as Guarantee_Client_Count,    sub4.Basel_Party_Group   from     (     select      sub3.Date_Valid,      sub3.Source_Entity_Code,      sub3.Entity_Code_7,      sub3.Coll_Instrument_Id,      sub3.Agreement_Id,      sub3.Global_Exposure_Amt_LC,      sub3.Global_Exposure_Amt_EUR,      da2.Global_Reporting_Flag,      da2.Party_Id,      dense_rank() over(partition by sub3.Date_Valid, sub3.Source_Entity_Code, sub3.Entity_Code_7, sub3.Coll_Instrument_Id order by da2.Party_Id) as Party_Id_Rank,      sub3.Basel_Party_Group     from       (       select        sub2.Date_Valid,        sub2.Source_Entity_Code,        sub2.Entity_Code_7,        sub2.Coll_Instrument_Id,        sub2.Basel_Party_Group,        sub2.Agreement_Id,        coalesce(max(dma1.Outstanding_Drawn_Amt_LC + Outstanding_Undrawn_Amt_LC) / count(dac3.Coll_Instrument_Id), 0) as Global_Exposure_Amt_LC,        coalesce(max(dma1.Outstanding_Drawn_Amt_EUR + Outstanding_Undrawn_Amt_EUR) / count(dac3.Coll_Instrument_Id), 0) as Global_Exposure_Amt_EUR       from         (         select          sub1.Date_Valid,          sub1.Source_Entity_Code,          sub1.Entity_Code_7,          sub1.Coll_Instrument_Id,          sub1.Basel_Party_Group_Corrected as Basel_Party_Group,          dac2.Agreement_Id         from           (           select            dac1.Date_Valid,            dac1.Source_Entity_Code,            dac1.Entity_Code_7,            dac1.Coll_Instrument_Id,            vcbp1.Basel_Party_Group,            max(vcbp1.Basel_Party_Group) over(partition by dac1.Date_Valid, dac1.Source_Entity_Code, dac1.Entity_Code_7, dac1.Coll_Instrument_Id order by vcbp1.Basel_Party_Group desc rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) as Basel_Party_Group_Previous,            max(vcbp1.Basel_Party_Group) over(partition by dac1.Date_Valid, dac1.Source_Entity_Code, dac1.Entity_Code_7, dac1.Coll_Instrument_Id order by vcbp1.Basel_Party_Group desc rows between 1 following and 1 following) as Basel_Party_Group_Next,            case             when vcbp1.Basel_Party_Group = '20'              and Basel_Party_Group_Next = '09' then '09'             when vcbp1.Basel_Party_Group = '0X'              and Basel_Party_Group_Next = '09' then '09'             when vcbp1.Basel_Party_Group = '0X'              and Basel_Party_Group_Previous = '20' then '20'             else vcbp1.Basel_Party_Group            end as Basel_Party_Group_Corrected           from ibfs_grp_m_risk.DM_Agreement_Collateral dac1            inner join ibfs_grp_m_risk.DM_Agreement da1 on dac1.Date_Valid = da1.Date_Valid             and dac1.Source_Entity_Code = da1.Source_Entity_Code             and dac1.Entity_Code_7 = da1.Entity_Code_7             and dac1.Agreement_Id = da1.Agreement_Id            left join ibfs_grp_rep.V_C_Basel_Portfolio vcbp1 on da1.Basel_Portfolio = vcbp1.Basel_Portfolio           group by dac1.Date_Valid, dac1.Source_Entity_Code, dac1.Entity_Code_7, dac1.Coll_Instrument_Id, vcbp1.Basel_Party_Group          ) sub1          inner join ibfs_grp_m_risk.DM_Agreement_Collateral dac2 on sub1.Date_Valid = dac2.Date_Valid           and sub1.Source_Entity_Code = dac2.Source_Entity_Code           and sub1.Entity_Code_7 = dac2.Entity_Code_7           and sub1.Coll_Instrument_Id = dac2.Coll_Instrument_Id         group by sub1.Date_Valid, sub1.Source_Entity_Code, sub1.Entity_Code_7, sub1.Coll_Instrument_Id, sub1.Basel_Party_Group_Corrected, dac2.Agreement_Id        ) sub2        left join ibfs_grp_m_risk.DM_Amount dma1 on sub2.Date_Valid = dma1.Date_Valid         and sub2.Source_Entity_Code = dma1.Source_Entity_Code         and sub2.Entity_Code_7 = dma1.Entity_Code_7         and sub2.Agreement_Id = dma1.Agreement_Id        left join ibfs_grp_m_risk.DM_Agreement_Collateral dac3 on sub2.Date_Valid = dac3.Date_Valid         and sub2.Source_Entity_Code = dac3.Source_Entity_Code         and sub2.Entity_Code_7 = dac3.Entity_Code_7         and sub2.Agreement_Id = dac3.Agreement_Id       group by sub2.Date_Valid, sub2.Source_Entity_Code, sub2.Entity_Code_7, sub2.Coll_Instrument_Id, sub2.Basel_Party_Group, sub2.Agreement_Id      ) sub3      inner join ibfs_grp_m_risk.DM_Agreement da2 on sub3.Date_Valid = da2.Date_Valid       and sub3.Source_Entity_Code = da2.Source_Entity_Code       and sub3.Entity_Code_7 = da2.Entity_Code_7       and sub3.Agreement_Id = da2.Agreement_Id    ) sub4   group by sub4.Date_Valid, sub4.Source_Entity_Code, sub4.Entity_Code_7, sub4.Coll_Instrument_Id, sub4.Global_Reporting_Flag, sub4.Basel_Party_Group  ) sub5  left join   (   select    Date_Valid,    Source_Entity_Code,    Entity_Code_7,    Coll_Instrument_Id,    coalesce(count(Guarantor_Party_Id), 0) as Guarantor_Count   from ibfs_grp_m_risk.DM_Collateral_Guarantor   group by Date_Valid, Source_Entity_Code, Entity_Code_7, Coll_Instrument_Id  ) dcg1 on sub5.Date_Valid = dcg1.Date_Valid   and sub5.Source_Entity_Code = dcg1.Source_Entity_Code   and sub5.Entity_Code_7 = dcg1.Entity_Code_7   and sub5.Coll_Instrument_Id = dcg1.Coll_Instrument_Id  left join ibfs_grp_m_risk.DM_Collateral dc1 on sub5.Date_Valid = dc1.Date_Valid   and sub5.Source_Entity_Code = dc1.Source_Entity_Code   and sub5.Entity_Code_7 = dc1.Entity_Code_7   and sub5.Coll_Instrument_Id = dc1.Coll_Instrument_Id  left join ibfs_grp_rep.V_C_Collateral_Nature vccn1 on dc1.Collateral_Nature_Code = vccn1.Collateral_Nature_Code   and dc1.Source_Entity_Code = vccn1.Source_Entity_Code  left join ibfs_grp_rep.V_C_SG_Collateral_Family vcsc1 on dc1.SG_Collateral_Family = vcsc1.SG_Collateral_Family  left join ibfs_grp_rep.V_C_SG_Collateral_Nature vcsc2 on dc1.SG_Collateral_Family = vcsc2.SG_Collateral_Family   and dc1.SG_Collateral_Nature = vcsc2.SG_Collateral_Nature ; comment on view %TABLE% is '%TLABL%';
62
PDM

IBFS_GRP_M_RISK
VF_DM_Deal_Guarantee_Detail_By_Guarantee_DT






Object
PDM_F4


12.04.2024 08:23:16+02:00


replace view %TABLE% as select  dito1.Date_Valid,  dito1.Entity_Code_7,  dito1.Source_Entity_Code,  dito1.Source_Entity_Id,  dito1.Org_Unit_Id,  dito1.Source_Entity_Long_Code,  dito1.Irregular_Status_Flag,  case   when dito1.Irregular_Status_Flag = 'Y' then 'Non regularise (hors delais)'   else 'Regularise (dans les delais)'  end as Irregular_Status_Flag_Desc,  case   when dito1.Irregular_Status_Flag = 'Y' then 'Not regularized (out of time)'   else 'Regularized (on time)'  end as Irregular_Status_Flag_Desc_EN,  dito2.Rank_Number,  sum(dito1.Tran_Amt_LC) as Tran_Amt_LC,  sum(dito1.Tran_Amt_EUR) as Tran_Amt_EUR from ibfs_grp_m_risk.DN_Irregular_Transaction_By_Officer dito1  inner join   (   select    Date_Valid,    Entity_Code_7,    Source_Entity_Code,    row_number() over(partition by Date_Valid order by sum(Tran_Amt_LC) desc, Source_Entity_Code) as Rank_Number   from ibfs_grp_m_risk.DN_Irregular_Transaction_By_Officer   where Irregular_Status_Flag in ('Y', 'N')    and Corporate_Retail_Segmentation = 'RETAIL'   group by Date_Valid, Entity_Code_7, Source_Entity_Code  ) dito2 on dito1.Date_Valid = dito2.Date_Valid   and dito1.Entity_Code_7 = dito2.Entity_Code_7   and dito1.Source_Entity_Code = dito2.Source_Entity_Code where dito1.Irregular_Status_Flag in ('Y', 'N')  and dito1.Corporate_Retail_Segmentation = 'RETAIL' group by dito1.Date_Valid, dito1.Entity_Code_7, dito1.Source_Entity_Code, dito1.Source_Entity_Id, dito1.Org_Unit_Id, dito1.Source_Entity_Long_Code, dito1.Irregular_Status_Flag, dito2.Rank_Number ;  comment on view %TABLE% is '%TLABL%';
62
PDM

IBFS_GRP_M_RISK
VF_DN_Monitoring_Override_Transaction_2_4B






Object
PDM_F4
Begin script does not contain key words "PARTITION BY" under reporting views

NULL


12.04.2024 08:23:16+02:00


replace view %TABLE% as select  dito1.Date_Valid,  dito1.Entity_Code_7,  dito1.Source_Entity_Code,  dito1.Source_Entity_Id,  dito1.Org_Unit_Id,  dito1.Source_Entity_Long_Code,  dito1.Irregular_Status_Flag,  case   when dito1.Irregular_Status_Flag = 'Y' then 'Non regularise (hors delais)'   else 'Regularise (dans les delais)'  end as Irregular_Status_Flag_Desc,  case   when dito1.Irregular_Status_Flag = 'Y' then 'Not regularized (out of time)'   else 'Regularized (on time)'  end as Irregular_Status_Flag_Desc_EN,  dito2.Rank_Number,  sum(dito1.Tran_Amt_LC) as Tran_Amt_LC,  sum(dito1.Tran_Amt_EUR) as Tran_Amt_EUR from ibfs_grp_m_risk.DN_Irregular_Transaction_By_Officer dito1  inner join   (   select    Date_Valid,    Entity_Code_7,    Source_Entity_Code,    row_number() over(partition by Date_Valid order by sum(Tran_Amt_LC) desc, Source_Entity_Code) as Rank_Number   from ibfs_grp_m_risk.DN_Irregular_Transaction_By_Officer   where Irregular_Status_Flag in ('Y', 'N')    and Corporate_Retail_Segmentation = 'RETAIL'    and     (     BHFM_Segmentation like '102%'      or BHFM_Segmentation = '10301'    )   group by Date_Valid, Entity_Code_7, Source_Entity_Code  ) dito2 on dito1.Date_Valid = dito2.Date_Valid   and dito1.Entity_Code_7 = dito2.Entity_Code_7   and dito1.Source_Entity_Code = dito2.Source_Entity_Code where dito1.Irregular_Status_Flag in ('Y', 'N')  and dito1.Corporate_Retail_Segmentation = 'RETAIL'  and   (   dito1.BHFM_Segmentation like '102%'    or dito1.BHFM_Segmentation = '10301'  ) group by dito1.Date_Valid, dito1.Entity_Code_7, dito1.Source_Entity_Code, dito1.Source_Entity_Id, dito1.Org_Unit_Id, dito1.Source_Entity_Long_Code, dito1.Irregular_Status_Flag, dito2.Rank_Number ;  comment on view %TABLE% is '%TLABL%';
62
PDM

IBFS_GRP_M_RISK
VF_DN_Monitoring_Override_Transaction_4_4B






Object
PDM_F4
Begin script does not contain key words "PARTITION BY" under reporting views

NULL


12.04.2024 08:23:16+02:00


replace view %TABLE% as select  dt3.Date_Valid as Date_Valid,  coalesce(dtpr1.SDM_Code, tpr1.SDM_Code) as Third_Party_Agency_OSCIS,  case   /* Pokud z predchoziho obdobi neni zadny preplatek - je kladna bilance, tak na reportu bude preplatek nula. /   when dt2.Comm_Payments_Bal_Amount > 0 then 0   / Preplatek na reportu bude zobrazovan jako kladna hodnota. Kdyby byla null hodnota, tak se prevede na nulu. /   else abs(coalesce(dt2.Comm_Payments_Bal_Amount, 0))  end as Comm_Overpayment_LC from   (   / Vyber provizi z tabulky Comm_Paid_Open /   select    cpo1.Date_Valid,    cpo1.Third_Party_Agency_Id   from grp_m_commission.Comm_Paid_Open cpo1   where cpo1.Comm_Segment_Code = 'EXT'    and cpo1.Comm_Record_Status_Code = 'CON'    and cpo1.Comm_Deleted_Flag_Code <> 'Y'    and cpo1.Manual_Payment_Flag = 'N'    and      (      (        B2B_Export = 'Y'         and Third_Party_Agency_Id = 'TPR10004349'       )       or         (         B2B_Export = 'N'          and            (            Third_Party_Agency_Id <> 'TPR10004349'             or Third_Party_Agency_Id is null           )        )     )   group by cpo1.Date_Valid, cpo1.Third_Party_Agency_Id      union all      / Vyber provizi z tabulky Comm_Paid_Close /   select    cpc1.Date_Valid,    cpc1.Third_Party_Agency_Id   from grp_m_commission.Comm_Paid_Close cpc1   where cpc1.Comm_Segment_Code = 'EXT'    and cpc1.Comm_Record_Status_Code = 'PAY'    and cpc1.Comm_Deleted_Flag_Code <> 'Y'    and cpc1.Manual_Payment_Flag = 'N'   group by cpc1.Date_Valid, cpc1.Third_Party_Agency_Id  ) dt3  left join   (   / Timto dostanu z tabulky D_Third_Party_Payment_Balance bilanci pro treti stranu k poslednimu dni v mesici. /   select    / Toto mi prevede puvodni datum, kdy doslo k pocitani provizi na posledni den v mesici tohoto data. */    (cast((dt1.Month_of_Date_Valid

'-01') as date) + interval '1' month - interval '1' day    ) as Date_Valid_for_Commissions,    dt1.Third_Party_Agency_Id,    dt1.Comm_Payments_Bal_Amount   from     (     select      /* Date_Valid obsahuje datum, kdy doslo k spocitani provizi. /      dtpp1.Date_Valid,      cast(cast(dtpp1.Date_Valid as format 'YYYY-MM') as char(7)) as Month_of_Date_Valid,      dtpp1.Third_Party_Agency_Id,      / Pro jistotu pridano coalesce, aby hodnota nebyla null. /      coalesce(dtpp1.Comm_Payments_Bal_Amount, 0) as Comm_Payments_Bal_Amount,      / Je zde z duvodu, kdyby se pripadne vypocet provizi spustil vickrat v danem mesici. /      row_number() over(partition by dtpp1.Third_Party_Agency_Id,        Month_of_Date_Valid order by dtpp1.Third_Party_Agency_Id asc,        dtpp1.Date_Valid desc       ) as Order_Dates     from grp_m_commission.DD_Third_Party_Payment_Balance dtpp1    ) dt1   where dt1.Order_Dates = 1  ) dt2 on dt3.Third_Party_Agency_Id = dt2.Third_Party_Agency_Id   and dt3.Date_Valid = dt2.Date_Valid_for_Commissions  / Toto spojeni je kvuli prevedeni Third_Party_Agency_Id na OSCIS. /  left join grp_m_commission.D_Third_Party_Relations dtpr1 on dt3.Third_Party_Agency_Id = dtpr1.Third_Party_Id  left join grp_m_commission.Third_Party tpr1 on substr(dt3.Third_Party_Agency_Id, 4, 8) = tpr1.SDM_Code   / Tato podminka je jiz trochu zbytecna, ale neuskodi. */   and dt3.Third_Party_Agency_Id = dtpr1.Third_Party_Agency_Id where coalesce(dtpr1.SDM_Code, tpr1.SDM_Code) is not null group by dt3.Date_Valid, Third_Party_Agency_OSCIS, Comm_Overpayment_LC ;  comment on view %TABLE% is '%TLABL%';
62
PDM

GRP_M_COMMISSION
VF_DM_Third_Party_Overpay






Object
PDM_F4
Begin script does not contain key words "PARTITION BY" under reporting views

NULL

12.04.2024 08:23:16+02:00


replace view %TABLE% as select  dt1.PRC_Code,  case   when GL_Chapter_Type_Count = 2 then dt1.GL_Chapter_Type2   else dt1.GL_Chapter_Type  end as GL_Chapter_Type,  dt1.Date_Valid,  coalesce(   case    when GL_Chapter_Type_Count = 2 then vhgc2.GL_Chapter_Type_Desc    else vhgc1.GL_Chapter_Type_Desc   end,   ''  ) as GL_Chapter_Type_Desc,  coalesce(   case    when GL_Chapter_Type_Count = 2 then vhgc2.GL_Chapter_Type_Desc_EN    else vhgc1.GL_Chapter_Type_Desc_EN   end,   ''  ) as GL_Chapter_Type_Desc_EN,  sum(dt1.Balance_Amt_SAP_LC) as Balance_Amt_SAP_LC,  sum(dt1.Balance_Amt_GL_LC) as Balance_Amt_GL_LC,  sum(dt1.Balance_Amt_GS_LC) as Balance_Amt_GS_LC,  sum(dt1.Balance_Amt_GL_LC - dt1.Balance_Amt_GS_LC) as Difference_Amt_GS_LC,  zeroifnull(cast(sum(dt1.Balance_Amt_GS_LC) / nullifzero(sum(dt1.Balance_Amt_SAP_LC)) as decimal(18, 4))) as   Coverage_Pct_SAP,  zeroifnull(cast(sum(dt1.Balance_Amt_GS_LC) / nullifzero(sum(dt1.Balance_Amt_GL_LC)) as decimal(18, 4))) as   Coverage_Pct_GL from   (   select    dgb1.PRC_Code,    case     when substr(PRC_Code, 1, 2) = 'IA' then 'A'     when substr(PRC_Code, 1, 2) = 'IP' then 'L'     when substr(PRC_Code, 1, 2) = 'IH' then 'S'     when substr(PRC_Code, 1, 2) = 'I7' then 'I'     when substr(PRC_Code, 1, 2) = 'II' then 'T'     when substr(PRC_Code, 1, 2) = 'I6' then 'E'     else dgb1.GL_Chapter_Type    end as GL_Chapter_Type2,    dgb1.GL_Chapter_Type,    dgb1.Date_Valid,    count(*) over(partition by dgb1.Date_Valid, dgb1.PRC_Code) as GL_Chapter_Type_Count,    sum(dgb1.Balance_Amt_SAP_LC) as Balance_Amt_SAP_LC,    sum(dgb1.Balance_Amt_GL_LC) as Balance_Amt_GL_LC,    sum(dgb1.Balance_Amt_GS_LC) as Balance_Amt_GS_LC   from ibfs_SEN_m_fin.DM_GL_Balance_Comparison_Conso dgb1   group by 1, 2, 3, 4  ) dt1  left outer join ibfs_SEN_m_fin.V_HC_GL_Chapter_Type vhgc1 on dt1.GL_Chapter_Type = vhgc1.GL_Chapter_Type   and dt1.Date_Valid between vhgc1.Start_Date and vhgc1.End_Date   and vhgc1.Source_Entity_Code = 'SEN'  left outer join ibfs_SEN_m_fin.V_HC_GL_Chapter_Type vhgc2 on dt1.GL_Chapter_Type2 = vhgc2.GL_Chapter_Type   and dt1.Date_Valid between vhgc2.Start_Date and vhgc2.End_Date   and vhgc2.Source_Entity_Code = 'SEN' group by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ;  comment on view %TABLE% is '%TLABL%';
62
PDM

IBFS_SEN_M_FIN
VF_DM_GL_Balance_Comparison_Conso






Object
PDM_F4
Begin script does not contain key words "PARTITION BY" under reporting views

NULL


12.04.2024 08:23:16+02:00


replace view %TABLE% as select  ctar3.Tran_Amount_Range_Code_1

ctar3.Tran_Amount_Range_Code_2

ctar3.Tran_Amount_Range_Code_3 as Tran_Amount_Range_Code_123,  ctar1.Tran_Amount_Range_Desc as Tran_Amount_Range_Desc_1,  ctar1.Tran_Amount_Range_Desc_EN as Tran_Amount_Range_Desc_EN_1,  ctar2.Tran_Amount_Range_Desc as Tran_Amount_Range_Desc_2,  ctar2.Tran_Amount_Range_Desc_EN as Tran_Amount_Range_Desc_EN_2,  ctar3.Tran_Amount_Range_Desc as Tran_Amount_Range_Desc_3,  ctar3.Tran_Amount_Range_Desc_EN as Tran_Amount_Range_Desc_EN_3,  ctar3.Tran_Amount_Range_Code_1 as Tran_Amount_Range_Code_1,  ctar3.Tran_Amount_Range_Code_2 as Tran_Amount_Range_Code_2,  ctar3.Tran_Amount_Range_Code_3 as Tran_Amount_Range_Code_3 from ibfs_MAR_EQD_dw.HC_Tran_Amount_Range_3 ctar3  inner join   (   select    Tran_Amount_Range_Code_1,    Tran_Amount_Range_Desc,    Tran_Amount_Range_Desc_EN   from ibfs_MAR_EQD_dw.HC_Tran_Amount_Range_1   qualify row_number() over(partition by Tran_Amount_Range_Code_1 order by Start_Date desc) = 1  ) ctar1 on ctar1.Tran_Amount_Range_Code_1 = ctar3.Tran_Amount_Range_Code_1  inner join   (   select    Tran_Amount_Range_Code_1,    Tran_Amount_Range_Code_2,    Tran_Amount_Range_Desc,    Tran_Amount_Range_Desc_EN   from ibfs_MAR_EQD_dw.HC_Tran_Amount_Range_2   qualify row_number() over(partition by Tran_Amount_Range_Code_1, Tran_Amount_Range_Code_2 order by Start_Date desc) = 1  ) ctar2 on ctar2.Tran_Amount_Range_Code_2 = ctar3.Tran_Amount_Range_Code_2   and ctar2.Tran_Amount_Range_Code_1 = ctar3.Tran_Amount_Range_Code_1 qualify row_number() over(partition by ctar3.Tran_Amount_Range_Code_1, ctar3.Tran_Amount_Range_Code_2, ctar3.Tran_Amount_Range_Code_3 order by ctar3.Start_Date desc) = 1 ; comment on view %TABLE% is '%TLABL%';
62
PDM

IBFS_MAR_EQD_REP
VP_C_Tran_Amount_Range






Object
PDM_F4
Begin script does not contain key words "PARTITION BY" under reporting views


12.04.2024 08:23:16+02:00


replace view %TABLE% as select  dito1.Date_Valid,  dito1.Entity_Code_7,  dito1.Source_Entity_Code,  dito1.Source_Entity_Id,  dito1.Org_Unit_Id,  dito1.Source_Entity_Long_Code,  dito1.Officer_Id,  dito1.Officer_Name,  dito1.Irregular_Status_Flag,  case   when dito1.Irregular_Status_Flag = 'Y' then 'Non regularise (hors delais)'   else 'Regularise (dans les delais)'  end as Irregular_Status_Flag_Desc,  case   when dito1.Irregular_Status_Flag = 'Y' then 'Not regularized (out of time)'   else 'Regularized (on time)'  end as Irregular_Status_Flag_Desc_EN,  dito2.Rank_Number,  sum(dito1.Tran_Cnt) as Tran_Cnt from ibfs_grp_m_risk.DN_Irregular_Transaction_By_Officer dito1  inner join   (   select    Date_Valid,    Entity_Code_7,    Source_Entity_Code,    Officer_Id,    row_number() over(partition by Date_Valid, Entity_Code_7, Source_Entity_Code order by sum(Tran_Cnt) desc, Officer_Id) as Rank_Number   from ibfs_grp_m_risk.DN_Irregular_Transaction_By_Officer   where Irregular_Status_Flag in ('Y', 'N')    and Corporate_Retail_Segmentation = 'RETAIL'    and     (     BHFM_Segmentation like '102%'      or BHFM_Segmentation = '10301'    )   group by Date_Valid, Entity_Code_7, Source_Entity_Code, Officer_Id  ) dito2 on dito1.Date_Valid = dito2.Date_Valid   and dito1.Entity_Code_7 = dito2.Entity_Code_7   and dito1.Source_Entity_Code = dito2.Source_Entity_Code   and dito1.Officer_Id = dito2.Officer_Id where dito1.Irregular_Status_Flag in ('Y', 'N')  and dito1.Corporate_Retail_Segmentation = 'RETAIL'  and   (   dito1.BHFM_Segmentation like '102%'    or dito1.BHFM_Segmentation = '10301'  ) group by dito1.Date_Valid, dito1.Entity_Code_7, dito1.Source_Entity_Code, dito1.Source_Entity_Id, dito1.Org_Unit_Id, dito1.Source_Entity_Long_Code, dito1.Officer_Id, dito1.Officer_Name, dito1.Irregular_Status_Flag, dito2.Rank_Number ;  comment on view %TABLE% is '%TLABL%';
62
PDM

IBFS_GRP_M_RISK
VF_DN_Monitoring_Override_Transaction_4_3A






Object
PDM_F4
Begin script does not contain key words "PARTITION BY" under reporting views

NULL


12.04.2024 08:23:16+02:00


replace view %TABLE% as select  Max_Dated.ECG_Group_ID, Max_Dated.ECG_Code_Desc  from   ( select  pgc.Party_Group_Id as ECG_Group_ID, pgc.Characteristic_Value_Vchar as ECG_Code_Desc from  ibfs_DZA_dw.H_Party_Group_Characteristics pgc Where Party_Group_Type = 'ECG'   and Characteristic_Type_Code = 'Name'  qualify row_number () over (partition by pgc.Party_Group_Id order by End_Date desc)=1  union   select 'XXXXXX' as ECG_Group_ID,  'No ECG' as ECG_Code_Desc from o_dwh_date.Dummy_Table  where Primary_Index = 1  union   select  'YYYYYY' as ECG_Group_Id,  'Unknown ECG' as ECG_Code_Desc from o_dwh_date.Dummy_Table where Primary_Index = 1 ) Max_Dated;   comment on view %TABLE% is '%TLABL%';
62
PDM

IBFS_DZA_REP
VP_ECG_Group






Object
PDM_F4
Begin script does not contain key words "PARTITION BY" under reporting views

NULL


12.04.2024 08:23:16+02:00


replace view %TABLE% as select  trim(cast(pec.Process_Error_Category_Id as integer))

'-'

trim(cast(pet.Process_Error_Type_Id as integer)) as Error_Category_Type_Id,  pet.Process_Error_Type_Name,  pet.Process_Error_Type_Name as Process_Error_Type_Name_EN,  pec.Process_Error_Categ_Name,  pec.Process_Error_Categ_Name as Process_Error_Categ_Name_EN from s_wmt.HC_WMT_Process_Error_Type pet  join s_wmt.HC_WMT_Process_Error_Category pec on pec.Process_Error_Category_Id = pet.Process_Error_Category_Id   and pet.End_Date between pec.Start_Date and pec.End_Date qualify max(pet.End_Date) over(partition by Process_Error_Type_Id)= pet.End_Date union select  'X-X' as Error_Category_Type_Id,  'Neznama chyba' as Process_Error_Type_Name,  'Unknown Error' as Process_Error_Type_Name_EN,  'Neznama chyba' as Process_Error_Categ_Name,  'Unknown Error' as Process_Error_Categ_Name_EN from o_dwh_date.V_DW_KB_Date ;      comment on view %TABLE% is '%TLABL%';
62
PDM

M_WMT_OM
VP_C_Error_Type






Object
PDM_F4
Begin script does not contain key words "PARTITION BY" under reporting views


12.04.2024 08:23:16+02:00




You may also have columns being defined as subselect, thus a "FROM" before the one corresponding to the "SELECT" surrounding the "PARTITION BY" you try to detect. As far as you will go in the complexity of the query you will always have some edges cases, esp. if you don't have real regexp to play with in the SQL dialect you are using.
One solution could be to try using SQL to filter the sources having "PARTITION BY" and do the final filtering in a client app with more adequate tools.

Why do you think the position of the OLAP-function is making a difference? It's the same step in Explain.

Try this
Select name,TEXT,CRDATE,refdate from sysobjects o join syscomments c on o.id=c.id where text like '%partition%by%'


Are you sure this an an answer to the question?

One solution could be to split the source code into lines, numbering them, then calculate the position of 'select' SPos, 'partition' PPos, 'from' FPos, keep the lines with at least one of these positions > 0.
Then you are looking in that intermediary result for a sequence of consecutive rows starting with SPos > 0, then any number of rows with PPos > SPos then a row with FPos > PPos.
This is trivially done in ORACLE with match_recognize, here is the code to inspire and translate in the dialect you are using (hope you have all the analytic functions you will need..)
select * from (
    select row_number() over(partition by name order by line) as rn, name, type, line, s, f, p from (
        select name, type, line, instr(lower(text),'select') as s, instr(lower(text),'partition') as p, instr(lower(text),'from') as f
        from user_source where name in (
            select name from user_source
            where instr(lower(text), 'partition by') > 0 
        )
    )   
    where f+s+p > 0
)
match_recognize
(
    partition by name, type
    order by rn
    measures sp.line as line_from, fp.line as line_to
    pattern( SP PP+ FP )
    define 
        SP AS s > 0,
        PP AS p > s,
        FP as f > p
)
;

TODO improve to take into account comments and avoid false positive...

I work in Teradata so expressions like match_recognize, pattern, etc. are not used in Teradata.. I added origin dataset where is visible I´m discussing about Table_Begin_Script attribute.

It was just an illustration of the concept... (at least it "works" in the env I tested here, giving the line ranges where the situations occur) translating it to use analytic functions and enhancing it to support comments and string literal (when the select, partition, from may be inside single quotes...) is still work to do...

Please, is it possible to demonstrate your solution on provided data in INPUT DATASET? It is little elusive for me in a form you created.

https://dbfiddle.uk/n-U8lBSj
again ORACLE syntax but without match_recognize and first attempt to take into account comments and text in literals, we still have to adapt the specific functions to your dialect, mainly the string manipulation and logical ones.
